# Calling acitivity from "OnMapClickListener()" not working

Tags: android, google-maps

I have tried a lot of examples but none of them worked.

```
mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title(latLng.latitude + " : " + latLng.longitude);
            mMap.clear();
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainMenu.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
```

Marker is added to the map but unfortunately it shows an error. When I click ok it goes to next activity.

Comment: I can't get your last sentence, is the app crashing? can you provide logs?

Comment: app is not crashing it shows error when i click ok it goes to next next activity

Comment: if the error is "Unfortunately app stopped" it is a crash. Please look at the logcat when it happens and check for log messages.
In any case, you are trying to animate the camera (which is a task that uses time), and at the same time opening a new activity. It could be the problem, you can either: Don't move the camera (your are opening a new activity, it has no sense), or add a callback to animate camera and open the next activity only when animation is finished.

Comment: thanks, removing animate camera works